# Can the sample space contain an impossible outcome?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

From my textbook:

> We roll a standard six-sided die. Then the sample space is $\Omega=$
> $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. Each sample point $\omega$ is an integer between 1
> and 6 . If the die is fair then each outcome is equally likely, in
> other words $$ P\{1\}=P\{2\}=P\{3\}=P\{4\}=P\{5\}=P\{6\}=\frac{1}{6}.
> $$ A possible event in this sample space is $$ A=\{\text { the outcome
> is even }\}=\{2,4,6\} \text {. } $$ Then $$
> P(A)=P\{2,4,6\}=P\{2\}+P\{4\}+P\{6\}=\frac{1}{2}. $$ The probability
> measure $P$ contains our assumptions and beliefs about the phenomenon
> that we are modeling.
>
> If we scratch away the five from the original fair die and turn it
> into a second two, the appropriate probability measure is $$
> Q\{1\}=\frac{1}{6},\, Q\{2\}=\frac{2}{6},\, Q\{3\}=\frac{1}{6},\,
> Q\{4\}=\frac{1}{6},\, Q\{5\}=0,\, Q\{6\}=\frac{1}{6} . $$ It is
> perfectly valid to assign a probability of zero to a nonempty event,
> as with $Q$ above.

**Question:** If the $5$ was scratched off the die, then wouldn't the sample space $\Omega$ change to $\{1,2,3,4,6\}$ since now $5$ could no longer be an outcome of the experiment?  And if so, then wouldn't it be true that there is no such event $\{5\}$ to even assign a probability to?

Comment: In a finitary case like this it makes no difference in this case whether you consider it an event with probability zero, or remove it from the event space.  Zero probability events can become important in infinitesimal contexts, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @user3716267 said in the comments, it's fine to have non-empty events with probability $0$, and it's pretty rare to remove them from the sample space.  In this case, removing it wouldn't really hurt anything, but doesn't give any benefits either.  In other cases, removing events with probability $0$ could definitely create problems.  For example, if $X$ is normally distributed, then $P(X=x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, but we definitely don't want to remove all the events $\{X=x\}$ or there would be nothing left!

Comment: So there wouldn't be an effect in the discrete case, but there could be, as you point out, in the continuous case?  Is that the crux of it?

Comment: @UngarLinski Yeah, that's basically right.  You can remove a finite (or countable) number of probability zero outcomes without changing much within that calculation, but there's no reason to, and there are times where you might be working with many probability measures and want them all to be defined on the same space.  In your example, if you removed $5$ from the sample space when defining $Q$, you would no longer have $P$ and $Q$ defined on the same probability space.

Answer (score 1):

> **Question:** If the $5$ was scratched off the die, then wouldn't the sample space $\Omega$ change to $\{1,2,3,4,6\}$ since now $5$ could no longer be an outcome of the experiment?  And if so, then wouldn't it be true that there is no such event $\{5\}$ to even assign a probability to?

Yes; yes.

Since the **sample space** of a probability experiment is [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_space) as its set of all possible outcomes, impossible outcomes like 5 and 7 are *not* elements of the sample space.

However, a sample space *can* contain zero-probability outcomes: such outcomes are possible, but happen almost never, and such a sample space has infinitely many outcomes. (One such outcome is hitting the exact centre of a dartboard.)